# Can’t Trigger GTM Tag for Google One Tapa

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-tag-manager, google-one-tap

I have a third party website that has implemented Google One Tap. GTM is installed and I have everything working except I cannot for the life of me get the google sign in to fire. I have tried XHR event tracking which works for every request but that. I tried CSS element selector to track the visibility and just cannot seem to find a way to trigger a sign in. If I had control over the backend of the website this would be simple but that’s not the case. Any tips or advice here would be greatly appreciated!

XHR Tracking
Custom HTML Tags
CSS selector / regex expressions